# Error while installing Python module in R via reticulate

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, reticulate

I am using R and I want to use a function I wrote in Python which needs to import:

`from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity`

I am trying to use the following code:

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("scikit-learn.neighbors.kde")
```

I have already installed sklearn with:
`py_install("scikit-learn")`

Also trying
`py_install("sklearn.neighbors.kde")`

does not work.

I get the following error/log:

```
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - scikit-learn.neighbors.kde

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


Error: one or more Python packages failed to install [error code 1]
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is `KernelDensity` not `kde`. If sklearn is installed, below should work:

```
library(reticulate)
sklearn = import("sklearn")
kde = sklearn$neighbors$KernelDensity

kde
<class 'sklearn.neighbors._kde.KernelDensity'>

X = matrix(rnorm(20),10,1)

kde = kde(kernel="gaussian")$fit(X)
kde$score_samples(X)

[1] -1.479458 -1.603451 -1.338018 -1.465263 -1.655933 -1.463628 -1.340137
 [8] -1.856085 -1.374666 -1.478621
```